# SSRS 2008 R2 Report Footer truncated while exported to Excel

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 for my report development.

The report works well from every perspective, exept for a small issue frustrating me.

So export to pdf works well and all the data exported well.

Export to excel truncate the footer and cut lot of data

I reached following Microsoft URL but its pointed to SQL Server 2012.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/736843/ssrs-2012-export-to-excel-footer-bug

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Excel header and footer sections support a maximum of 256 characters, including markup. If this limit is exceeded, the Excel renderer removes markup characters starting at the end of the header and/or footer string to reduce the number of total characters. If all markup characters are removed and the length still exceeds the maximum, the string is truncated starting from the right.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159836.aspx